# How to clear Text component using ref in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to clear Text Component using ref on timeout but can't find.

```
<Text style={{ color: "#fff" }} ref={text => this._text = text}>
              {isKeyValid === undefined
                ? null
                : isKeyValid
                ? "Key is been verified."
                : "Your key is invalid or expired."}
</Text>

clearErrorMessages = () => {
   setTimeout(() => {
   //something like that here which i have no idea  
   this._text.clear() 
   }, 2000);
}
```

Any idea about this guys thanks...

Comment: I don't think text component has clear() method, it's actually for TextInput. You can easily tackle this issue by using state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to clear text in a `<Text>` component. 
You can do this: take whatever value you want to display in state variable and set it to empty string when required.

in constructor:

```
this.state={
  value:"myvalue",
}
```

in render

```
<Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
```

then on any action/function you want to clear the text do this:

```
this.setState({value:""});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approach, different method then refs,

take one state and make it false by default in a constructor,
and set it to true after time out. Also, use it in your a condition
see this,

```
<Text style={{ color: "#fff" }} ref={text => this._text = text}>
              {isKeyValid === undefined && this.state.isCleared
                ? null
                : isKeyValid
                ? "Key is been verified."
                : "Your key is invalid or expired."}
</Text>

clearErrorMessages = () => {
   setTimeout(() => {
   //something like that here which i have no idea  
   this.setState({isCleared:true});
   }, 2000);
}
```

Don't forget to initialize it in constructor.